# System.out.println

Tags: java

По каким то непонятным причинам при написании System.out.println, ни IDE, ни компиляция через консоль не распознает команду println, ровно как и просто print. 
Произошло внезапно, буквально неделю назад все было окей. Читаю книжку по Java и не совсем понимаю в чем проблема.

```
public class TestClass {
    System.out.println("Something");
}
```

Comment: Ошибку то какую выдает? import System на месте?

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'println'. так System ж входит в пак java.lang. Зачем его импортировать? Программа дропается именно на println.

Comment: Можете показать полностью код всего файла что у вас там написано

Comment: А добавьте в вопрос кусок со своими импортами

Comment: Добавил код. Импортов нету, просто тест класс с одной командой. Пробовал в консоле и в IntelliJ IDEA. Ни там, ни там не работает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я бы на месте компилятора также ругался. Дали класс, без методов, а внутри код. Ваш класс должен выглядеть как минимум так

```
class TestClass
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Something");
    }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю. Не кодил уже недели две и совсем забыл об обьявлении функции main.